# What's the largest domain needed for $ f(x)=(x-1)^2$ to be injective?

Tags: functions

> Given $f(x)=(x-1)^2$, to make it injective and to obtain $f^{-1}(x)$, we need to restrict the domain, either from $(-\infty, 1]$ or $[1,\infty)$. Which is the **larger** domain?

I'm thinking that it's $(-\infty, 1]$ since $0$ is the midpoint of $(-\infty,\infty)$, it makes sense that it's the larger domain.

Is my reasoning sound or is it flawed?

Thanks.

Comment: How "it makes sense"? It is correct, but for a much simpler reason: $\;y=(x-1)^2\;$ is an upwards parabola tangent at $\;x=1\;$ to the $\;x$-axis and, thus, it is injective on *any* of its two branches: either the  going-down one $\;(-\infty,1]\;$ or the going-up one $\;[1,\infty)\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio - It makes sense because the **number of values** from $(-\infty,1]$ is more than from $[1,-\infty)$. Am I correct in saying that the number of values for $(-\infty,0]$ is equal to $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Well @Alfred: no, the "number of values" in both cases is, in a very well defined and definite sense, exactly the same...and yes for your second question.

Comment: @DonAntonio - If the second question is true, wouldn't that mean that range of values of $(-\infty,1]\neq [1,\infty)$? Since the values $[0,1]$ are "taken out" from $[0,\infty)$ and "put into" $(-\infty,0]$ to get $(-\infty,1]$?

Comment: Oh, it may be that those ranges are different, @Alfred (though they are not, by the way), but that does **not** mean one has "more" values than the other. Within infinities realms things can go a little weird.

Comment: @DonAntonio - I see, going to have to do more research, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both domains are half-lines, so by any meaningful measurement they are the same size.  Your argument is flawed because we want "size" to be reflection-invariant. Reflecting the half-line $[1,\infty)$ at the point $1$ gives the other half-line.

Also, we want "size" to be translation-invariant, so sliding $[1,\infty)$ to $[a,\infty)$ for any $a$ should give a set of the same "size".  This seems paradoxical, since $[1,\infty)$ includes points that $[3,\infty)$ does not -- yet they are the same size.  However this counterintuitive situation occurs all the time when dealing with infinite sets.